# What is an Ultimate Air Trap (UAT)?

Tags: fuel

I am confused about what an Ultimate Air Trap is.
I understand somewhat that its task is to remove the air bubbles in the fuel feed to an engine. But how does it work? 
How is it different from a normal RC Fuel tank? For example I am unable to see the difference between the following two. (The first is a normal fuel tank, the second one is a UAT.)

1. [Fuel Tank](http://www.rchyderabad.com/plane-accessories/fuel-tanks/fuel-tank-for-rc-planes.html)

[image]

2. UAT

[image]

or [this](https://pilot-rc.com/jet-uat-tank/):

[image]

Internal Parts:

[image]

**Other Questions:**

1. Why is the tube to the rear end in the case of the fuel tank but only to the middle in the UAT? Also, is there a reason why is it hanging mid-air (not touching the wall)?
2. Is the white part in picture 4 a clunk or some kind of filter? I have read of Bubble trap in microfluidics is it a similar device?